# Connection timeout in ADo.NET

Tags: c#, ado.net

```
using (SqlConnection Connect = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["templateconnection"].ConnectionString))
       {
        string strQuery = "update ActionAudits set ChecksumValue=( select CHECKSUM(Id,DateAndTimeOfAction,ActionType,RecordType,ReferenceNumber,UserFk,LocationFk,PatientFk,IPAddress) from ActionAudits with(nolock) Where Id=" + id + ")where Id=" + id;
            SqlCommand cmdChecksumValue = new SqlCommand(strQuery, Connect);
            Connect.Open();
            value = Convert.ToInt32(cmdChecksumValue.ExecuteNonQuery());
            Connect.Close();
        }
```

While executing the `Convert.ToInt32(cmdChecksumValue.ExecuteNonQuery())` 
it shows

**ERROR:connection timeout error**

Comment: i think because of your update query it takes to long to execute

Comment: Hello, sql injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

set cmdChecksumValue .CommandTimeout to a larger number. Default is 30 seconds.